# How can I seamlessly handle migrations in production databases during deployment in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, production-environment

Is it standard practice to put db:migrate in my capistrano task, maybe before updating the code?  I don't want to forget to add a column to production and get errors so I feel like there should be a seamless way to do this.  Is there anything wrong with doing it the way I mentioned?  ...just wondering what the standard practice is here

Answer (score 2):

Do `cap -T` and read about `cap:deploy:migrate` and `cap:deploy:migrations`.

Comment: :migrations => "deploy and then run migrations", while :migrate => "run migrations on the current deployment"